# Should indirect tags be deleted?

Tags: discussion, tags

When I created [cucumber-junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cucumber-junit) it was for a question [In Cucumber-JUnit, is there a way to control the order in which features get reported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170705/in-cucumber-junit-is-there-a-way-to-control-the-order-in-which-features-get-rep) that was specifically to the integration between Cucumber and JUnit.

However, many of the questions with the tag are not specifically about the integration between JUnit and Cucumber as intended by [cucumber-junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cucumber-junit) but seem to be added just because they have the [cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cucumber) and [junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/junit) tags, so why not add [cucumber-junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cucumber-junit) as well.

Should taggings like these to be edited to remove the tag?

- [Integrating JMeter with Cucumber+Ruby+Selenium framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400995/integrating-jmeter-with-cucumberrubyselenium-framework)
- [Same Step Definitions in Cucumber Gherkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604267/same-step-definitions-in-cucumber-gherkins)
- [Alternate way to run Cucumber without JUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739347/alternate-way-to-run-cucumber-without-junit)
- [Automating Browser with Cucumber with the use of Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876791/automating-browser-with-cucumber-with-the-use-of-parameter)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452230/cannot-run-android-junit-tests

Specifically: should tags be deleted when the question isn't about the tag directly but they may or may not be using the technology of the tag in question?

---

PS - this only came up because I just earned the "Taxonomist" badge for the tag, and was seeing if anything was worth learning from.

Comment: Is it likely that there will be many questions that are really about the integration of Cucumber and JUnit? If not, then the tag probably shouldn't have been created in the first place.

Comment: Well it about the specific library that does the integration not integration between the two. It's also very annotation heavy configuration with room for confusion, and at least half of the 50 tagged questions I'd say are valid in the 2 years since it was created so I think so. It has room to grow and helps

Comment: You could probably do a better job on the tag excerpt and wiki, which should describe when the tag should be used, rather that purely what library in question is... Other than that, taggers gonna tag. The best you can do is clean up after them.